# How can I calculate vertical velocity with MPU9250?

Tags: c++, quaternions, esp32, mpu6050

What I am trying to archive with this sensor is a variometer.   The main function of variometer is to tell how many meters / second it is [going up or down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEwSQu5lGZQ).

I have a ESP32 Dev module connected to a MPU9250.  I used [this library](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_MPU-9250-DMP_Arduino_Library) (with a little fix), and I made sure the sensor is working.  Although I get [all different kinds of methods](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_MPU-9250-DMP_Arduino_Library/blob/master/src/SparkFunMPU9250-DMP.h) from this library, it is just overwhelming to understand how to put them all together to get vertical velocity.

There is a project called `prunkdump/arduino-variometer`, and this also builds a variometer.  Looking at [the codes](https://github.com/prunkdump/arduino-variometer/blob/c4a7bc5b3ede9ab5ee15aebb06d925f4292d99e8/libraries/vertaccel/vertaccel.cpp#L220), I see quaternions have to do with this.

If I stick with [sparkfun/SparkFun_MPU-9250-DMP_Arduino_Library](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_MPU-9250-DMP_Arduino_Library), am I able to get vertical velocity in the similar method?